# Android: FileObserver doesn't trigger OPEN event on some phones

Tags: android, fileobserver

I'm developing an app that notices when a file inside a directory is opened by another application. I therefore use a `FileObserver` that observes the directory.

When I'm running my application on a Nexus 5 `(Android 6.0.1)` or Huawei P10 `(Android 8.0.0)`, I'm able to receive a `FileObserver.OPEN (32)` event when the other application opens a file inside the observed directory. I'm getting events in the following order:

```
 Event Type: 1 (Access)
 Event Type: 1 (Access)
 Event Type: 16 (CLOSE_NOWRITE)
 Event Type: 32 (OPEN)
```

Testing the application with the same application setup on a Galaxy S9+ `(Android 8.0.0)` and a Google Pixel `(Android 8.1.0)` the event is not triggered when a file is opened.

```
 Event Type: 1 (Access)
 Event Type: 1 (Access)
 Event Type: 16 (CLOSE_NOWRITE)
```

The `FileObserver.OPEN` event is missing. I can guess that the problem does not originate in the Android version as the S9+ shares one with the P10, but maybe I'm wrong.

Does anybody know what could be the problem, as I am pretty stuck here?

Comment: What does it do on a budget phone?

Comment: I now tested it on a Moto G Play (7.1.1) and Honor 8 (7.0.0). They both trigger the OPEN event. Thats all phones I have available.